# Shiny: Download Plot

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard, shiny-reactivity

I am aware that this is a recurring question, but I must be drowning in a cup of tea.
Have a look at the self-contained (a bit lengthy, admittedly) script below.
Everything works like a charm apart from the capability to download the generated plot.
I am positive the fix must be a one-liner, but so far no luck.
I can create a button to download the plot, but somehow I cannot get the code to understand that gpl_fin is the plot it is supposed to save.
Any help is super-appreciated!
Thanks!

```
library(shiny)
library(Cairo)   # For nicer ggplot2 output when deployed on Linux
library(tidyverse)
library(scales)
library(DT)
library(patchwork)
library(viridis)


my_pal <- viridis(3)[1:2]

my_ggplot_theme2 <- function(legend_coord){
    theme_bw()+

    theme(legend.title = element_text(vjust=1,lineheight=1, size=14 ),
          panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
          plot.title = element_text(lineheight=.8, size=24, face="bold",
          vjust=1),legend.text = element_text(vjust=.4,lineheight=1,size = 14 ),
          axis.title.x = element_text(size = 20, vjust=1),
                axis.title.y = element_text(size = 20, angle=90, vjust=1),
                axis.text.x = element_text(size=15, colour="black", vjust=1),
          axis.text.y = element_text(size=15, colour="black", hjust=1),
                          legend.position = legend_coord,
           strip.background = element_rect(colour = 'blue',
                           fill = 'white', size = 1, linetype=1),
                strip.text.x = element_text(colour = 'red', angle = 0,
                                     size = 12, hjust = 0.5,
                    vjust = 0.5, face = 'bold'),
                   strip.text.y = element_text(colour = 'red', angle = 0,
                    size = 12, hjust = 0.5,
                    vjust = 0.5, face = 'bold'),

          )
}


df_ini <- structure(list(year = c(2013L, 2013L, 2014L, 2014L, 2015L, 2015L, 
2015L, 2015L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 
2017L, 2013L, 2013L, 2014L, 2014L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 
2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2017L, 2017L), entity = c("TOTAL", 
"TOTAL", "TOTAL", "TOTAL", "SPE", "TOTAL", "SPE", "TOTAL", "SPE", 
"TOTAL", "SPE", "TOTAL", "SPE", "TOTAL", "SPE", "TOTAL", "TOTAL", 
"TOTAL", "TOTAL", "TOTAL", "SPE", "TOTAL", "SPE", "TOTAL", "SPE", 
"TOTAL", "SPE", "TOTAL", "TOTAL", "TOTAL"), IN_STOCKS = c(432, 
125429, 1651, 125153, 953, 2056, 19674, 125519, 880, 2153, 17157, 
134931, 251, 1192, 13749, 124002, 2800, 47661, 2591, 49980, 0, 
3246, 0, 53401, 0, 3134, 0, 53078, 3419, 54270), OUT_STOCKS = c(532, 
34303, 677, 34692, 0, 640, 1584, 34808, 0, 603, 443, 37696, 0, 
199, 797, 38092, 1903, 148787, 1756, 152491, 0, 2557, 0, 152812, 
0, 2375, 0, 159034, 3046, 148449), IN_FLOWS = c(354, 13737, 1244, 
39, -197, 226, 1121, 2111, -302, 83, 710, 10095, -563, -733, 
-3598, -9440, -570, -7988, -241, -448, 0, -355, 0, 3722, 0, 133, 
0, -3950, 324, -23), OUT_FLOWS = c(NA, -5521, 23, 241, 0, -76, 
369, -375, 0, 9, -255, 4695, 0, -370, 0, 3458, 432, 13504, 19, 
-2956, 0, 1023, 0, -1730, 0, -129, 0, 9227, 713, -10335), Reporter = c("Belgium", 
"Belgium", "Belgium", "Belgium", "Belgium", "Belgium", "Belgium", 
"Belgium", "Belgium", "Belgium", "Belgium", "Belgium", "Belgium", 
"Belgium", "Belgium", "Belgium", "France", "France", "France", 
"France", "France", "France", "France", "France", "France", "France", 
"France", "France", "France", "France"), Partner = c("Austria", 
"France", "Austria", "France", "Austria", "Austria", "France", 
"France", "Austria", "Austria", "France", "France", "Austria", 
"Austria", "France", "France", "Austria", "Belgium", "Austria", 
"Belgium", "Austria", "Austria", "Belgium", "Belgium", "Austria", 
"Austria", "Belgium", "Belgium", "Austria", "Belgium")), row.names = c(NA, 
-30L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))


reporters <- df_ini$Reporter %>% unique %>% sort
partners <- df_ini$Partner %>% unique %>% sort


ui <- fluidPage(    
    sidebarLayout(
  sidebarPanel(       
    selectInput("reporterlabel",
            "Reporter:",
            reporters ## , multiple=T
            ),
selectInput("partnerlabel",
            "Partner:",
            partners),



# Button
downloadButton("downloadData", "Download the data"),
 downloadButton("save", "save")

),


mainPanel(
    plotOutput("tradeplot"
               ) ,
    tableOutput("table")

)
)
)





server <- function(input, output) {



    filtered_data <- reactive({

      df_ini %>% filter(Reporter %in% input$reporterlabel,
                        Partner %in% input$partnerlabel) %>%
          arrange(desc(year)) %>%
          group_by(year,Reporter, Partner) %>%
          summarise(IN_STOCKS=sum(IN_STOCKS),
                    OUT_STOCKS=sum(OUT_STOCKS),
                    IN_FLOWS=sum(IN_FLOWS),
                    OUT_FLOWS=sum(OUT_FLOWS)) %>%
          ungroup() %>%
          mutate(Entity="Special Entity plus Total",
                 NACE="All NACE Actitivities") %>%
          select(year,  Reporter,   Partner, Entity, NACE, everything()) %>%
          arrange(desc(year))


  })





    output$tradeplot <- renderPlot({

options( scipen = 16 )


        df1 <- filtered_data() %>%
            select(-c(IN_FLOWS, OUT_FLOWS)) %>%
            pivot_longer(c(OUT_STOCKS, IN_STOCKS), names_to="direction",
                         values_to="val") 


        df2 <- filtered_data() %>%
            select(-c(IN_STOCKS, OUT_STOCKS)) %>%
            pivot_longer(c(OUT_FLOWS, IN_FLOWS), names_to="direction",
                         values_to="val")


        my_rep <- df1$Reporter[1]

        my_par <- df1$Partner[1]


gpl12 <- df1 %>%
    ggplot(aes(x = year, y = val, fill=direction)) +
    geom_bar(stat="identity", position="dodge")+
    my_ggplot_theme2("top")+
     scale_fill_manual(NULL, labels=c("Inward Stocks","Outward Stocks" ),  values=my_pal)+  
      scale_y_continuous(breaks=pretty_breaks(n=4))+
      scale_x_continuous(breaks = function(x) unique(floor(pretty(x))))+
      xlab("Year")+
      ylab("Stocks\n(Mio \u20ac)")+
      labs(title = paste("Reporter: ", my_rep, "\nPartner: ", my_par))


gpl34 <- df2 %>%
    ggplot(aes(x = year, y = val, fill=direction)) +
    ##   geom_point(size=3) +
    ## geom_line(size=1) +
    geom_bar(stat="identity", position="dodge")+
     scale_fill_manual(NULL, labels=c("Inward Flows","Outward Flows" ),  values=my_pal)+  
    my_ggplot_theme2("top")+
      scale_y_continuous(breaks=pretty_breaks(n=4))+
      scale_x_continuous(breaks = function(x) unique(floor(pretty(x))))+
      xlab("Year")+
      ylab("Flows\n(Mio \u20ac)")+
      labs(title = NULL)


gpl_fin <- gpl12/gpl34

gpl_fin


    }

  )

    output$table <- renderTable(filtered_data())  







  # Downloadable csv of selected dataset ----
  output$downloadData <- downloadHandler(
    filename = function() {
      ## paste(input$dataset, ".csv", sep = "")
      paste("data_extraction", ".csv", sep = "")

    },
    content = function(file) {
      write.csv(filtered_data(), file, row.names = FALSE)
    }
  )




output$save <- downloadHandler(
    filename = "save.png" ,
    content = function(file) {
     ggsave(tradeplot(), filename = file)

    })





}



shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Yeah, to @A.Suliman's point, it looks like `gpl_fin` is a nonsense object, as you can't  divide one plot by another. Are you trying to stack the two plots or something?

Comment: Due to to the patchwork library,  that is a valid combinations of plots.  The app runs, but I cannot save the plot

Comment: @larry77 as you can see in the R console after "Saving 11.4 x 4.55 in image" _Warning: Error in tradeplot: could not find function "tradeplot"_, so move the entire plot part into a `reactive` expression outside `renderPlot`  and it will work fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if It's okay to post this. This is exactly what [a.suliman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8467042/a-suliman) mentioned

```
library(shiny)
library(Cairo)   # For nicer ggplot2 output when deployed on Linux
library(tidyverse)
library(scales)
library(DT)
library(patchwork)
library(viridis)


my_pal <- viridis(3)[1:2]

my_ggplot_theme2 <- function(legend_coord){
  theme_bw()+

    theme(legend.title = element_text(vjust=1,lineheight=1, size=14 ),
          panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
          plot.title = element_text(lineheight=.8, size=24, face="bold",
                                    vjust=1),legend.text = element_text(vjust=.4,lineheight=1,size = 14 ),
          axis.title.x = element_text(size = 20, vjust=1),
          axis.title.y = element_text(size = 20, angle=90, vjust=1),
          axis.text.x = element_text(size=15, colour="black", vjust=1),
          axis.text.y = element_text(size=15, colour="black", hjust=1),
          legend.position = legend_coord,
          strip.background = element_rect(colour = 'blue',
                                          fill = 'white', size = 1, linetype=1),
          strip.text.x = element_text(colour = 'red', angle = 0,
                                      size = 12, hjust = 0.5,
                                      vjust = 0.5, face = 'bold'),
          strip.text.y = element_text(colour = 'red', angle = 0,
                                      size = 12, hjust = 0.5,
                                      vjust = 0.5, face = 'bold'),

    )
}


df_ini <- structure(list(year = c(2013L, 2013L, 2014L, 2014L, 2015L, 2015L, 
                                  2015L, 2015L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 
                                  2017L, 2013L, 2013L, 2014L, 2014L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 
                                  2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2017L, 2017L), entity = c("TOTAL", 
                                                                                        "TOTAL", "TOTAL", "TOTAL", "SPE", "TOTAL", "SPE", "TOTAL", "SPE", 
                                                                                        "TOTAL", "SPE", "TOTAL", "SPE", "TOTAL", "SPE", "TOTAL", "TOTAL", 
                                                                                        "TOTAL", "TOTAL", "TOTAL", "SPE", "TOTAL", "SPE", "TOTAL", "SPE", 
                                                                                        "TOTAL", "SPE", "TOTAL", "TOTAL", "TOTAL"), IN_STOCKS = c(432, 
                                                                                                                                                  125429, 1651, 125153, 953, 2056, 19674, 125519, 880, 2153, 17157, 
                                                                                                                                                  134931, 251, 1192, 13749, 124002, 2800, 47661, 2591, 49980, 0, 
                                                                                                                                                  3246, 0, 53401, 0, 3134, 0, 53078, 3419, 54270), OUT_STOCKS = c(532, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                  34303, 677, 34692, 0, 640, 1584, 34808, 0, 603, 443, 37696, 0, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                  199, 797, 38092, 1903, 148787, 1756, 152491, 0, 2557, 0, 152812, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                  0, 2375, 0, 159034, 3046, 148449), IN_FLOWS = c(354, 13737, 1244, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  39, -197, 226, 1121, 2111, -302, 83, 710, 10095, -563, -733, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  -3598, -9440, -570, -7988, -241, -448, 0, -355, 0, 3722, 0, 133, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  0, -3950, 324, -23), OUT_FLOWS = c(NA, -5521, 23, 241, 0, -76, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     369, -375, 0, 9, -255, 4695, 0, -370, 0, 3458, 432, 13504, 19, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     -2956, 0, 1023, 0, -1730, 0, -129, 0, 9227, 713, -10335), Reporter = c("Belgium", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            "Belgium", "Belgium", "Belgium", "Belgium", "Belgium", "Belgium", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            "Belgium", "Belgium", "Belgium", "Belgium", "Belgium", "Belgium", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            "Belgium", "Belgium", "Belgium", "France", "France", "France", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            "France", "France", "France", "France", "France", "France", "France", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            "France", "France", "France", "France"), Partner = c("Austria", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 "France", "Austria", "France", "Austria", "Austria", "France", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 "France", "Austria", "Austria", "France", "France", "Austria", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 "Austria", "France", "France", "Austria", "Belgium", "Austria", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 "Belgium", "Austria", "Austria", "Belgium", "Belgium", "Austria", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 "Austria", "Belgium", "Belgium", "Austria", "Belgium")), row.names = c(NA, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        -30L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))


reporters <- df_ini$Reporter %>% unique %>% sort
partners <- df_ini$Partner %>% unique %>% sort


ui <- fluidPage(    
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(       
      selectInput("reporterlabel",
                  "Reporter:",
                  reporters ## , multiple=T
      ),
      selectInput("partnerlabel",
                  "Partner:",
                  partners),



      # Button
      downloadButton("downloadData", "Download the data"),
      downloadButton("save", "save")

    ),


    mainPanel(
      plotOutput("tradeplot"
      ) ,
      tableOutput("table")

    )
  )
)





server <- function(input, output) {



  filtered_data <- reactive({

    df_ini %>% filter(Reporter %in% input$reporterlabel,
                      Partner %in% input$partnerlabel) %>%
      arrange(desc(year)) %>%
      group_by(year,Reporter, Partner) %>%
      summarise(IN_STOCKS=sum(IN_STOCKS),
                OUT_STOCKS=sum(OUT_STOCKS),
                IN_FLOWS=sum(IN_FLOWS),
                OUT_FLOWS=sum(OUT_FLOWS)) %>%
      ungroup() %>%
      mutate(Entity="Special Entity plus Total",
             NACE="All NACE Actitivities") %>%
      select(year,  Reporter,   Partner, Entity, NACE, everything()) %>%
      arrange(desc(year))


  })


  tradeplot <- reactive({
    options( scipen = 16 )


    df1 <- filtered_data() %>%
      select(-c(IN_FLOWS, OUT_FLOWS)) %>%
      pivot_longer(c(OUT_STOCKS, IN_STOCKS), names_to="direction",
                   values_to="val") 


    df2 <- filtered_data() %>%
      select(-c(IN_STOCKS, OUT_STOCKS)) %>%
      pivot_longer(c(OUT_FLOWS, IN_FLOWS), names_to="direction",
                   values_to="val")


    my_rep <- df1$Reporter[1]

    my_par <- df1$Partner[1]


    gpl12 <- df1 %>%
      ggplot(aes(x = year, y = val, fill=direction)) +
      geom_bar(stat="identity", position="dodge")+
      my_ggplot_theme2("top")+
      scale_fill_manual(NULL, labels=c("Inward Stocks","Outward Stocks" ),  values=my_pal)+  
      scale_y_continuous(breaks=pretty_breaks(n=4))+
      scale_x_continuous(breaks = function(x) unique(floor(pretty(x))))+
      xlab("Year")+
      ylab("Stocks\n(Mio \u20ac)")+
      labs(title = paste("Reporter: ", my_rep, "\nPartner: ", my_par))


    gpl34 <- df2 %>%
      ggplot(aes(x = year, y = val, fill=direction)) +
      ##   geom_point(size=3) +
      ## geom_line(size=1) +
      geom_bar(stat="identity", position="dodge")+
      scale_fill_manual(NULL, labels=c("Inward Flows","Outward Flows" ),  values=my_pal)+  
      my_ggplot_theme2("top")+
      scale_y_continuous(breaks=pretty_breaks(n=4))+
      scale_x_continuous(breaks = function(x) unique(floor(pretty(x))))+
      xlab("Year")+
      ylab("Flows\n(Mio \u20ac)")+
      labs(title = NULL)


    gpl_fin <- gpl12/gpl34

    gpl_fin

  })


  output$tradeplot <- renderPlot({

    tradeplot()

  }

  )

  output$table <- renderTable(filtered_data())  







  # Downloadable csv of selected dataset ----
  output$downloadData <- downloadHandler(
    filename = function() {
      ## paste(input$dataset, ".csv", sep = "")
      paste("data_extraction", ".csv", sep = "")

    },
    content = function(file) {
      write.csv(filtered_data(), file, row.names = FALSE)
    }
  )




  output$save <- downloadHandler(
    filename = "save.png" ,
    content = function(file) {
      ggsave(tradeplot(), filename = file)

    })





}



shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Believe me, at least for me this is very OK! Thanks everyone for taking their time to help me out.

Comment: @larry77 Please mark the answer as answered if it had solved the issue. This helps others coming to this.!